# Shell read line extract data into variable to test for if/else statements the print line

Tags: bash, shell, variables, readline

I have a tsv infile with the below text. In this example script I want to read the input file line by line then using sed extract the username into a variable. The username variable is then tested to match the line for SUE which if matched the line is printed. However, when running the script the output file is blank. If I REM out the IF statement and UNREM the printf "$name\n" line I get the below output file. Is there anyway to extract data from a file into a variable to use in a IF statement?

Also I have to use the two sed statements to insert a line at the beginning of the input file and then remove it with the second sed statement. Otherwise the first line is skipped in the output. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help with the problem.

**infile**

```
JOHN    IS      FAST\n
SUE     IS      OK\n
STEVE   IS      SLOW\n
```

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "" > output1
#Insert blank line at beginning of input file. Without this line the first line is skipped
sed -i '1 i\\' infile
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ] ; do
    #Extract first word in line which is the name
    name=$(sed -E 's/(.*)(\t)(.*)(\t)(.*)/\1/p')
    #printf "$name\n"
    if [[ $name =~ "SUE" ]] ; then
        printf "$line\n"
    fi
done < infile  > output
#Remove the blank line inserted above at the beginning of the input file
sed -i -r '/^\s*$/d' infile
```

**outfile**

```
JOHN\n
JOHN\n
SUE\n
SUE\n
STEVE\n
STEVE\n
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have posted your efforts in form of code in your question, please keep it up. Could you please post sample of input and expected output in your question for more clarity thank you.

Comment: In the line that's supposed to extract the `name`, no input is supplied to the `sed` command, so it'll read from infile (stealing input you meant to be read into `line`). You probably want `name=$(sed ... <<<"$line")`. But it looks to me like the whole loop could be replaced by `awk -F$'\t' '$1 ~ /SUE/' infile > output`.

Comment: Gordon Davisson - That did it!!! Thanks so much for your help. I had tried  name=$(sed ... "$line") and several variations and could not determine why the line was not being parsed.